# Using obscureText and MaskTextInputFormatter for some character in TextField

Tags: flutter

How can I use `obscureText` and `MaskTextInputFormatter` for some characters in `TextField`?

[image]

Comment: when you say **some characters**; what do you mean? Is there any pattern as to which characters/numbers needs to be hidden?

Comment: If I use obscureText - all characters will be hidden. I want to hide characters like in image above. For example, hide last two characters: "hello - hel**"